# Mapping an image onto a torus

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I'm currently working in Blender 2.78 using cycles trying to create a realistic toroidal/doughnut planet. The problem I'm having is mapping an image onto a torus.

The result should be something like the picture below.

[image: A toroidal planet]

Comment: I have tried unwrapping the torus after making seams along an equator and a meridian in the uv editor. I have also tried only making one seam along a  meridian and unwrapping as a  cylinder.

Comment: An option is to map the image into a subdivided plane and bend that plane to make a torus. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39735/how-could-i-animate-a-plane-into-a-pipe-and-then-a-pipe-into-a-torus

Comment: I see the thought did occur to me to do that. I will test it out and let you know if it's successful.

Comment: Your method worked very well. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think your original marking of seams would have worked fine if you had used the Follow Active Quads unwrap method with a "corner" face selected and active.

Comment: Yeah, I was having trouble with that, and it seems that I was just missing a step. Following active quads works better and is less cumbersome. You just have to straighten out a quad using the line selection tool, follow active quads and then scale the net of the tours to fit the map.