# How to roll up a plane/create a rolled yoga mat?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm trying to create a rolled up [yoga mat](https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/1408/1408/sport-mat/j/9/g/173-61-cosco-yoga-mat-power-original-imae4afj6p2gbjdy.jpeg?q=90). I thought I could use the cloth simulator and run a physics animation to make a subdivided mesh roll itself up but I couldn't get it to work. Everything I tried just resulted in a cloth that was bent in lots of different directions.

So then I thought maybe I could run an animation to make the mesh roll itself around a cylinder. I guess for this to work I'd need to be able to pin the mesh to the cylinder, and then animate the cylinder rotating a few times. I guess I can rotate the cylinder by creating keyframes with 0 degrees of rotation then say 10 * 360 degrees rotation. But how can I parent one end of the mesh to the cylinder in the first place?

Or is there a better way to do this?

I'd also like to be able to have the corners of the mat slightly curled up when it's flat (e.g. [like this](http://proactivehealthgroup.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Yoga-Mat--600x384.jpg) but less pronounced) which makes me think perhaps physics is the way to go after all?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39735/how-could-i-animate-a-plane-into-a-pipe-and-then-a-pipe-into-a-torus/39737#39737 Also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4YY7XBpAeWE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible way:

First create a bezier like this:

[image]

which has control points like

[image]

then add the mat in a convenient position (I used a subdivided plane with solidify and subsurf) then use a curve modifier to the above bezier

[image]

if you animate the bezier along X you get this:

[image]

There could be other ways of course but I hope it helps you.