# Animated rotation of plane to solid

Tags: animation

I was wondering if there was a way to animate the rotation of a plane to generate the solid of the rotation. This is to create an informative math video on Integration.

So, for example, taking a rectangle and rotating it 360 degrees on the x-axis at the base of the rectangle to 'reveal' by animation that it created a cylinder.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: An animation that makes plane to cylinder?

Comment: If yes than its related to [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39735/how-could-i-animate-a-plane-into-a-pipe-and-then-a-pipe-into-a-torus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a vertical plane, the pivot point have to be on the side of it.
2. Add a screw modifier
3. Select the first frame what you want on the timeline, type in 0 for angle, stay the mouse above the "Angle" box then hit "I"
4. Select the final frame on the timeline type in 360 for angle, stay the mouse above the "Angle" box then hit "I"

[image]

Fill the ends:

Duplicate the plane twice, delete the modifier from the new ones and add the same values on the same frames for the Z rotation as the screw modifier has, like you did it in the 3. and 4. steps.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Your suggestion was what I was after - thank you. I noticed, however, that when you add the modifier, the initial instance of the mesh disappears. I assume you just make a copy of the mesh and position it where the first one would be? Again, I appreciate your help.
Ian