# Straighten a curved cylinder?

Tags: modeling, objects, edit-mode

I have a model I made some time ago that mainly consists of what is essentially a detailed cylinder shape. When I initially made it, I modeled it with a baked in curve for a natural shape, but my plan was to rig the object so I could reference how it looked as it moved around. At the time, I didn't realize that baking in a curve would make it harder to handle in rigging and posing. I'm wondering if there's any way to easily reverse or otherwise ease a curve like this?

[image: a curved cylinder, comparable to what i have right now]

Pictured above is similar to what I have now.

[image: A straightened curve.]

Pictured above is similar to what I'd like to end up with.

I'm pretty new to blender, but I would assume that one could, by some means, force all of the long edges of a face loop to be the same length? Normalize the long edges' lengths, somehow? If you could do that for all of the edges, per face loop, it'd essentially negate the curve completely.

[image: if all selected long edges were the same length...]

Pictured above: If all the selected long edges were the same length, that segment would essentially no longer be curved.

Obviously, one *could* just manually rotate and re-align each segment...

[image: manual correction]

...but that's imprecise and takes a long time.

I'm wondering if there's any quicker way to do something like that. Thanks in advance for your time, and for any help that you might offer!

Comment: You already have it straight in your second picture. What else is missing?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos The models that I included for the images are really just meant to be demonstrative, so that there is both an observable "current" and an observable "goal" state. For this reason, I made the straight cylinder first, then curved it, so as to *replicate* the issue I was experiencing, but in a very controlled environment. I just took the second screenshot *before* I curved the cylinder, but in the more complex project I'd like to apply this to, I can't just go back to before I curved it, unfortunately.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245282/how-to-bend-geometry-with-geometry-nodes https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72118/advanced-curving-and-linking/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/problems-with-curve-modifier https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34598/how-to-curve-my-mesh https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39735/how-could-i-animate-a-plane-into-a-pipe-and-then-a-pipe-into-a-torus/

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Forgive me if I'm mistaken, but the resources you've linked seem mainly concerned with the curving of a straight mesh, as opposed to the straightening of a curved one ? ^^;;
One of those talks about a simple curve modifier though, which.. kind of works? but it's still very warped. https://i.imgur.com/pYtxCHl.png
I'm also looking into the bezier-curves post now, though.